# Why does Vim load buffers from old session when new one is started?

Tags: buffers, sessions

The situation is this:

I have 2 sessions: *s1.vim* and *s2.vim*.
First one was saved with files **A**, **B**, **C** in buffers list.
Second one was saved with file **A**.

Next I start vim: `vim -S s1.vim`. `:ls` shows **A**, **B**, **C**. Then I source second session. `:so s2.vim`. And instead of **A** `:ls` shows **A**, **B**, **C** again. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Session" is simply a Vim script. You can read it - it does not try to wipe any existing buffers (except maybe one it was started from and only if it was blank). It works well on Vim startup, but may leave extra buffers floating around if you load it later.

Currently there's no way to change this behaviour. If you really feel it wrong (although, I should say, it's the most safe option), you can open an issue on Vim's Github page.

Comment: Vim documentation on ```:mksession``` explicitly says that session file when executed with ```:source``` unloads currently loaded buffers and restores new ones.
[mksession help page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession)

Comment: My bad. This is indeed a default behavior. I found an issue on Github regarding this question. There was a mistake on documentation since session file doesn't contain code to unload any buffers except current one.  [github](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2864)

Comment: @whysoserious It says "unloads all buffers", not "wipes" them. Indeed, it closes all windows that could result in unloading all buffers (though it's tunable).

Comment: yes, for some reason I thought that unloaded buffer is no longer in the buffer list. Thanks

Comment: @whysoserious `:h bufloaded()` vs `:h buflisted()`.